# ERROR: Unable to find module with Gradle path ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, capacitor

I'm developing a mobile app with Ionic 4, Capacitor and some Cordova plugins and have run into a problem when attempting to run the app on Android. Android Studio refuses to run the project and prints the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to find module with Gradle path ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins' (needed by module 'app'.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue is resolved by syncing Gradle files again manually:

[image]

Answer (score 28):

If you cant find the folder capacitor-cordova-android-plugins inside the android project folder, you need to run a capacitor command to create it (and update plugin variables):

```
npx cap sync
```

Comment: This is exactly what was wrong. Why would it not auto generate this?